# Weighted rankings in excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to develop a robust way to provide an average event assessment score.

I am working with several different organizations. An event will happen and I will provide an assessment score per event that is based on 2 criteria. The criteria scores are combined to give an overall assessment score for the event.

I then wanted to get aggregate scores for an organization based on the events related to that organization. I use `AVERAGEIFS` formulas to give me the average score across the 2 criteria for each organization. However, when I use the `AVERAGEIFS` formula to calculate the overall assessment score (which is a function of the 2 criteria scores) the results don't give a correct picture. Right now a couple of organizations have really high scores, but that is because they only have had 1 or 2 events associated with them; this makes those organizations stand-out when they shouldn't. I need to build on this below formula to include `COUNT` functions that will either add or remove padding

```
=AVERAGEIFS($C$2:$C$100, $B$2:$B$100, "Organization A", $C$2:$C$100, ">0")
```

Something that counts the number of times "Organization A" appears in Column B, if it is <5 times, then the `AVERAGEIFS` result will be multiplied by 0.7 (or some other random number), or if "Organization A" appears >50 times than `AVERAGEIFS` result will be multiplied by 1.2 and so on.

I've incorporated suggestions from the comments to structure the following formula:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(C2:C100, B2:B100, "A", C2:C100, ">0") * IF(COUNTIF(B2:B100, "A") < 3, 0.7, IF(COUNTIF(B2:B100, "A") < 10, 0.9, IF(COUNTIF(B2:B100, "A") > 30, 1.1, IF(COUNTIF(B2:B100, "A") > 50, 1.2, 1))))
```

This formula works, but for some reason, using data that I have, I know the `AVERAGEIFS` value for "A" should be multiplied by 1.2, as there are more than 50 instances of "A" in Col. B. The result the above formula gives multiplies by 1.1.

Not sure where I am going wrong here.

In addition, I've expanded the above formula to include other padding factors:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(C2:C100, B2:B100, "A", C2:C100, ">0") * IF(COUNTIF(B2:B100, "A") < 3, 0.7, IF(COUNTIF(B2:B100, "A") < 10, 0.9, IF(COUNTIF(B2:B100, "A") > 30, 1.1, IF(COUNTIF(B2:B100, "A") > 50, 1.2, 1)))) * IF((AND(B2:B100, "A"), COUNTIF(S2:S100, "yes")>1), 1.1, 1))
```

Here I get an error message: "The formula you typed contains an error".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=AVERAGEIFS($C$2:$C$100, $B$2:$B$100, "Organization A", $C$2:$C$100, ">0")*IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$100, "Organization A")<5, 0.7, IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$100, "Organization A")>50, 1.2, 1))
```

should do the trick